# How to Apply OWASP in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, owasp

i just read about the Top 10 OWASP , and i just wondering if this applicable on WCF ?

is there another list of OWASP for WCF ?

please note that i am still a newbie on WCF world.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your WCF service is running behind the firewall (which is the most common case), OWASP doesn't apply. A typical set up when using WCF is to have a WebAPI or MVC interfacing the internet and running the WCF services as back-end services talking to your databases.

Comment: Thanks , assuming that we need to expose our WCF SOAP services to the Internet ,what should i look for (from the owasp list) ?\

Comment: If your service has access to the database, make sure you are using SQL parameters/ stored procedures only to pass the data. Make sure the user input is always validated. Since this is a WCF service it is good practice to use Token only for authentication to avoid CSRF attacks. HTTPS only as transport mode. I would implement my service such that every end point is secure by default and I will explicitly open those that are not. If the data you are exposing is extremely sensitive I would even whitelist the domain that can have access to the resources. - Thankyou Soma.

Comment: Editors' note: the amendment to remove the signature was correct. Editors should always remove signatures here - the profile card is thought to be sufficient for this purpose.

Answer (score 1):

WCF is a framework to build services. You can either build SOAP or REST services with it. Most of the [OWASP top 10](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet) applies to services built with WCF when you expose them on the web or when they accept input from untrusted sources indirectly.

Some of them, like XSS and CSRF only apply to WCF REST services exposed to the internet, but others like [A1, A2, A5, A6, A7 and A9](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet#OWASP_Top_Ten_Cheat_Sheet) are also applicable to WCF SOAP services. Running your service behind a firewall does not mitigate any of these threats. Also, in some circumstances, SOAP services may be exposed to the internet also.

Comment: Thanks , assuming that we need to expose our WCF SOAP services to the Internet ,what should i look for (from the owasp list) ?

Comment: @AhmadAbu-Hamideh You'll need to at least address these: security configuration (use https bindings), input validation (reject malicious input), user authentication (validating security token), user authorization (is user allowed to call this method).